# Why would you have to use the test command in a php shell injection?

Tags: shell, security, code-injection

I saw someone doing this in a php shell injection:

```
test | cat /var/backup/secret.txt
```

But why would they use the `test |`? It seems like it's a useless command doing nothing, why not just run the `cat` command instantly?

Comment: This is probably better asked at https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Actually, the whole pipe looks pointless: `test` does not write to stdout, and this invocation of `cat` does not read stdin.....